# NSMutableDictionary Literal

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

```
CLBeaconRegion *region;
NSMutableDictionary *beacons;
....

beacons[region] = beacons;
```

Is the code above setting `beacons` key as `region` to the value of `beacons`?  I thought the key has to be a `string` in a `NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

```
beacons[region] = beacons;
```

That's the same as:

```
[beacons setObject:beacons forKey:region];
```

The first is just syntactical shortcut for second.  Either way, it's probably not what you want, since it doesn't *usually* make sense to set a dictionary key/value pair that points back to the dictionary itself.  What are you actually trying to do?

The key in a dictionary doesn't have to be a string, but it does have to conform to the [`NSCopying` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/index.html), see the [definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject:forKey:):

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject
           forKey:(id<NSCopying>)aKey
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow the Airlocate project for iBeacons and was kind of confused:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: `[beacons setObject:beacons forKey:region];` does not make sense.

Comment: It technically calls `-setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`, not `-setObject:forKey:` when using the literal syntax, but the signature is the same.

Answer (score 0):

`beacons[region] = beacons;` seems to be incorrect as you are adding the `beacons` dictionary to itself under the key `region`.

Note that when using key-value coding the key must be a string see [Key-Value Coding Fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I took this code from Apple sample program: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: No, that statement is not in the linked app. File and line number please? The closest I can find is: `self.rangedRegions[region] = beacons;`.